# Chrome debugging for PHP

Tags: php, debugging, google-chrome

I know that chrome debugging can be used for javascript

But i have been told that it can be used to debug PHP as well.
This seams absurd to be because server side scripts such as PHP are invisible to browsers.

Is it true that google chrome can debug PHP
if yes
How is is done?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to ask, why you didn't first ask Google for "Chrome PHP debug". Here's, what i found: http://craig.is/writing/chrome-logger